# TimePickerDialog and TimePicker

Tags: android, datetimepicker

```
onCreate(...) {
...
showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
...
Button btnOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                       “Time selected:” +
                       timePicker.getCurrentHour().toString() +
                       “:” + timePicker.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}

onCreateDialog(...) {
    return new TimePickerDialog(...)
}
```

Above is a code sample from an Android book. I was wondering how timePicker knows the current hour and current minute. timePicker is only defined in onCreate. When onCreateDialog is called with showDialog(), it returns a TimePickerDialog that in no way seems to know about timePicker, yet timePicker is able to get the current hour and minute to toast it.

Comment: After apply some parts of this code, toast shown bottom of the phone. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) contains a [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) widget which in turn implements code for getting the current time. The sample code is referencing the [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) in [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) directly by assuming that [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) will always contain a [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) with the id: `timePicker`.

However, you don't need to *magically* know the id of the [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html). You can implement the [TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html) callback interface which has access to the embedded [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) via the `onTimeChanged (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)` method as illustrated in this [Time Picker tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `showDialog()`, the dialog is created in the Activity's View hierarchy.  So when the next line does `findViewById(R.id.timePicker)`, it finds the `TimePicker` inside the dialog, presumably which has the id of `timePicker`, and saves a reference to it in `timePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

On `onCreate` Method you only have the reference.

when you click on btnOpen you call `getCurrentHour()` and `getCurrentMinute()` to get the current time.